# How to generate localized datetime from "20201023T200457Z" and from "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"?

Tags: java, android, android-date

I have this start datetime: "20201023T200457Z" (it seem to be UTC0000)
how can I convert/generate it with this "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss" pattern in local time on a mobile?

I get this result: Fri Oct 23 20:04:57 GMT+02:00 2020
with this code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", Locale.getDefault());
    Date startGMTInput = df.parse(start);
    Log.e(TAG, "start: " + startGMTInput.toString());// -> Fri Oct 23 20:04:57 GMT+02:00 2020
```

But my target is to get: 2020-10-23 22:04:57 //because I'm in GMT+2 timezone

Comment: Well, you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse _and_ format dates so just create another one with the pattern you want.

Comment: Use `java.time`.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time either through desugaring or ThreeTenABP

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Let’s first define the formatters we need:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd'T'HHmmssX");
private static final DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
```

( `DateTimeFormatter` is thread-safe, so we can safely declare them static.) Do the time zone conversion explicitly:

```
    String startString = "20201023T200457Z";
    Instant start = inputFormatter.parse(startString, Instant.FROM);
    String target = start.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(outputFormatter);
    System.out.println(target);
```

Output in my time zone (currently at offset +02:00 like yours):

> 20201023 22:04:57

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in. Only in this case use the method reference `Instant::from` instead of the constant `Instant.FROM`.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the great ideas and links! Finally I found a solution without to use java8 and external libs to backward compatibility. First I converted input format with SimpleDateFormat, then set the timezone to GMT, and another SimpleDateFormat I converted it with the out format.

Answer (score 0):

Set your timezone to GMT+2 before any date operations.

```
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2"));
```

Comment: I have doubts whether it will help. Could you demonstrate with a complete example that it will? And/or even better, explain in more detail how?